# Silverlight datagrid binding - how to bind child dictionary item as parent class property?

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, datagrid

I have a class like this to be bind to a datagrid as itemsource:

```
public class Item
{
  public int Id { get; set; }   
  public string Status { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, string> DynamicProperties { get; set; }
}
```

I want to bind `List<Item>` to a silverlight datagird and display columns as this

id | Status | DynamicProperties[0] | DynamicProperties[1] | ... ...

How can I implement this?

Comment: also, the dictionary is dynamic, the item count of the the dictionary is unknown until runtime.

Comment: and it's silverlgiht 4 / mvvm light

Comment: found this which solved my problem - http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2011/01/23/populating-a-datagrid-with-dynamic-columns-in-a-silverlight-application-using-mvvm.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Silverlight 4 and above [bindings with string indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645024%28VS.95%29.aspx#indexdata) are supported. You simple bind with a path as follows:

```
{Binding Path=DynamicProperties['propertyIndex']}
```

For earlier version s of Silverlight, the solution is much more complex, [as described on my blog](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/binding-a-silverlight-3-datagrid-to-dynamic-data-via-idictionary-updated/).

If you want to create columns directly, just do this via code-behind. The blog post referenced above shows how to create a DataGrid dynamically.

Comment: thanks. as the dictionary is dynamic, the item count of the the dictionary is unknown until runtime. I am thinking to bind in code behind but not sure in which event handler I should implement this.

Comment: @Xin Updated my answer - please see the referenced blog post, it has an example of a DataGrid with dynamic columns.